# Zip Multiple folder - Python

Tags: python, relative-path, python-zipfile

I am working on zip the multiple folder in python
When i ran the code it's creating name1.zip and name2.zip and open the name1.zip file it only showing the file1.pdf.

What i am trying is when i open name1.zip file it will come with parent folder name1

Folder structure

test --> name1 --> file1.pdf

Could someone help me out
Thanks
This is my code:

```
import os

import zipfile

path = "/Users/Documents/test"

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser(path)))

for folder in os.listdir(path):
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('{0}.zip'.format(os.path.join(path, folder)), 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(path, folder)):
        for filename in files:
            zipf.write(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, filename)), arcname=filename)
    zipf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what the `arcname` parameter is for. Try

```py
zipf.write(
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, filename)),
    arcname=os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, filename), start=path)
)
```

instead of

```py
zipf.write(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, filename)), arcname=filename)
```

Also, have a look at [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Makes for more readable code IMHO.